# Android JSON: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse the JSON response get from the server and I am getting the error message: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Here Is the logcat:

```
08-28 18:56:08.083: W/System.err(1037): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"content":"<p class=\"bodytext\">erhalten Sie einen Überblick über die Aktivitäten der SKBF im Jahr 2011 im aktuellen Jahresbericht.<br \/><br \/><a href=\"de\/portraet\/auftrag\/#c113\" class=\"internal-link\" >SKBF Jahresbericht 2011<\/a><\/p>","pubDate":"01.06.12","category":"Allgemeine News","title":"SKBF Jahresbericht 2011","description":"Wenn Sie wissen wollen, was die SKBF macht","link":"http:\/\/www.skbf-csre.ch\/de\/news\/news-detail\/?tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=2&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=80&cHash=1274043c236945bf6e592329e6742ebf"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-28 18:56:08.083: W/System.err(1037):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
08-28 18:56:08.083: W/System.err(1037):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:484)
08-28 18:56:08.093: W/System.err(1037):     at com.example.skbf_csre.SKBFActivity.onCreate(SKBFActivity.java:55)
08-28 18:56:08.093: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
08-28 18:56:08.093: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
08-28 18:56:08.103: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
08-28 18:56:08.103: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-28 18:56:08.103: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
08-28 18:56:08.103: W/System.err(1037):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 18:56:08.113: W/System.err(1037):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
08-28 18:56:08.113: W/System.err(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
08-28 18:56:08.113: W/System.err(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 18:56:08.113: W/System.err(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-28 18:56:08.123: W/System.err(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
08-28 18:56:08.123: W/System.err(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
08-28 18:56:08.123: W/System.err(1037):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I amtrying to do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title"));
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please post a sample JSON document as test case. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the JSON can be found here: http://www.skbf-csre.ch/apps/iphone/rss/?displayFormat=JSON&language=german&function=newsList

Comment: How jsonArray is being achieved? Error at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject can be because what stored in jsonArray is no longer an array. Try making it JsonObject first then only jsonArray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you aren't digging quite deep enough to get to your data. What you have is an array containing multiple arrays, each of which contains an object. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray innerJsonArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
        JSONObject jsonObject = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("title"));
}
```