# JSONArray vs. JSONObject

Tags: android, json, api, parsing

Why is my JSONArray being returned as a JSONObject? Or maybe I'm mistaken. I'm trying to parse some data from the JSON located [here](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=11212&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=e85709956f235457122411). I read previous SO questions regarding this topic(such as the question asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164161/android-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject) and what I've learned is that it's important to correctly distinguish between a JSONArray and a JSONObject.

It looks to me like it's both, more specifically it looks like a JSONArray of JSONObjects, each of which contains name:value pairs. I'm trying to "dig a little deeper to get my data" like the answer suggested, but I'm getting a JSONException at line 96, which is this one. I thought maybe "data" is not the correct name of the array, but the JSON is printed in the LogCat only when I use that string. Any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Line 96
weatherData = json.getJSONArray("data");

I've pasted the relevant code below.

```
public String getWeatherData() {

    String url = "http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q="
            + zipCode
            + "&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=e8570995";

    // Create a JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON String from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    // Log.e("WeatherProvider", "Got JSON from URL");
    /*
     * try { currentCond = json.getString("data"); } catch (JSONException
     * e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e1.printStackTrace(); }
     */

    try {
        // Get array of weather data
        weatherData = json.getJSONArray("data");

        Log.e("WeatherProvider", "JSONArray is not null");

        if (weatherData != null) {
            // loop through the data array
            for (int i = 0; i < weatherData.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray innerJSONArray = weatherData.getJSONArray(i);
                JSONObject object = innerJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Store each json item in a variable
                currentCond = object.getString("value");

                Log.e("WeatherProvider", "current conditin is "
                        + currentCond);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return currentCond;
}
```

}

LOGCAT:

```
11-25 12:03:33.439: W/System.err(4502): org.json.JSONException: Value {"weather":        [{"windspeedMiles":"19","winddirection":"W","date":"2012-11-25","precipMM":"0.0","winddirDe    gree":"280","winddir16Point":"W","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/  \/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"}],"tempMinC":"4","windspeedKmph":"31","tempMaxC":"7","weatherCode":"113","tempMaxF":"44","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Sunny"}],"tempMinF":"39"},{"windspeedMiles":"13","winddirection":"WNW","date":"2012-11-26","precipMM":"0.0","winddirDegree":"290","winddir16Point":"WNW","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"}],"tempMinC":"4","windspeedKmph":"21","tempMaxC":"8","weatherCode":"113","tempMaxF":"46","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Sunny"}],"tempMinF":"40"},{"windspeedMiles":"13","winddirection":"NW","date":"2012-11-27","precipMM":"4.5","winddirDegree":"320","winddir16Point":"NW","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png"}],"tempMinC":"0","windspeedKmph":"21","tempMaxC":"8","weatherCode":"296","tempMaxF":"47","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Light rain"}],"tempMinF":"32"},{"windspeedMiles":"13","winddirection":"WNW","date":"2012-11-28","precipMM":"0.0","winddirDegree":"300","winddir16Point":"WNW","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"}],"tempMinC":"1","windspeedKmph":"21","tempMaxC":"7","weatherCode":"113","tempMaxF":"44","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Sunny"}],"tempMinF":"33"},{"windspeedMiles":"15","winddirection":"WNW","date":"2012-11-29","precipMM":"0.0","winddirDegree":"286","winddir16Point":"WNW","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"}],"tempMinC":"2","windspeedKmph":"23","tempMaxC":"4","weatherCode":"113","tempMaxF":"40","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Sunny"}],"tempMinF":"35"}],"current_condition":[{"observation_time":"04:33 PM","cloudcover":"75","pressure":"1013","visibility":"16","temp_C":"4","temp_F":"39","windspeedMiles":"19","precipMM":"0.0","winddirDegree":"270","winddir16Point":"W","weatherIconUrl":[{"value":"http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"}],"humidity":"48","windspeedKmph":"30","weatherCode":"116","weatherDesc":[{"value":"Partly Cloudy"}]}],"request":[{"type":"Zipcode","query":"11212"}]} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at com.brightr.weathermate.providers.WeatherProvider.getWeatherData(WeatherProvider.java:90)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at com.brightr.weathermate.activities.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4263)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-25 12:03:33.449: W/System.err(4502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Just an aside, it is nice if you post all of the code you need, and not any more. In this case, you really only needed the few lines of code that crashed, along with defining variables, and the error stack...

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do the trick. I'll edit my post to only show the relevant code. But just for extra clarity and going forward, how would I go about getting the other arrays "request" and "current_condition" below? Basically the same approach, just using separate JSONArrays ie; weatherData = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("request") etc etc??
)

Comment: Exactly. Now you are getting how to work with JSON;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an array, but rather it is a JSON object consisting of an array called weather. This should do the trick:

```
weatherData = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("weather");
```

Comment: "data" also contains the single-element arrays "request" and "current_condition", but yes, that looks like the root of the problem.

Comment: Hey, I know I already asked..but if you don't mind shedding some light on another issue I'm having. How would I go about retrieving multiple objects of the same "name". For example, the array "weather" contains 5 objects of the name "date" and I will need all 5 of these, as well as others. Any help would be great appreciated, thanks again!